# Setting devexpress PopupColorEdit color

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I want to set color to PopupColorEdit from code, in xaml it works like this:

```
<dxe:PopupColorEdit  Color="#FFE5E5E5" x:Name="gridTopCP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
```

But if i try setting it from code:

```
     Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Dim boja As Color = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32("#FFE5E5E5", 16))
    gridTopCP.Color = boja
End Sub
```

I get error: `Value of type 'Color' cannot be converted to 'Color'`

Comment: Use `System.Windows.Media.Color`, not `System.Drawing.Color`.

Answer (score 0):

`ColorEdit.Color = Color.FromRgb(150, 18, 30);`

U need to pass the RGB values not the HTML code here u will find the [RGB values](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/)